# How to translate the "Confirm Contribution" button on Contribution pages

Tags: contribution-page, translation

I have a multilingual CiviCRM install with 3 languages.
"Multiple Languages Support" is activated, and the fields with translation icon next to them have all been translated.

But I also need to translate the button "Confirm Contribution" at the bottom of the Contribution pages.
How can I achieve this?

Since this needs to be translated to 3 languages, I can not use Word Replacements (word replacements is not multilingual, so it uses the same replacement in all languages)

Comment: The Drupal string translation does not see this string either, so I can not use that to translate this string either.

Comment: Can anyone confirm that multilingual word replacement should be possible in civicrm 5.13.5? Would need to know whether it is civicrm or me ... because I don't see it.

Answer (score 1):

Multilingual word replacement support is the topic of both [CRM-14349](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-14349) and [CRM-19683](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19683).  CRM-19683 just had [a patch merged](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/9446), which should be available in the January 2017 release of CiviCRM.  You can patch it now if you're patch-savvy.  Please try it and see if it solves your problem - or wait until January 2017, upgrade to CiviCRM 4.7.15+ and see if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

**One way of doing this would be:**

In this case you need to write an java script (Main.extra.tpl) to change the value of the button based on the language selected

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure but if I remember correctly there is actually a word replacement page for each language (at least it was like that in 4.3.x). If you are on the word replacement page and switch the ui language, it should provide you with a page that does replacements for English --> Current UI Language.

Another option would be to translate the strings on transifex (if they are coordinated via transifex) and update your transltion afterwards. Please find more information on the translation process here: https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=88408149

Comment: Nope, this does not work unfortunately.
And the database table "civicrm_word_replacement" does not have fields for other languages, you can only set one replacement in them, that is used in all languages.